# SQL Select insert with Condition (between these two tables)

Tags: mysql

I am new to Sql. And I have two tables which

```
table_A (student_id, last_name, email, schoolA, ...)

table_B (student_id, last_name, email, schoolB, ...)
```

And in table_A, some student_id was Null or ''(empty).

> select the student_id from table_B insert into table_A's student_id colm
>
> when only match last_name and email, also when A.student_id is Null or
>   Empty.

here was what I thought

```
INSERT INTO table_A (student_id) 
SELECT student_id 
    From table_B 
    WHERE table_A.last_name = table_B.last_name AND table_A.email = table_B.email 
        AND table_A.student_id ='' OR table_A.student_id = NULL
```

I know the sql which I wrote is not make any sense. And I just want to get a simple example or some idea.

Thank your!

Comment: This looks way too much like homework.

Comment: because i use student id and shcool? haha.  nope, this is not a home work. actually this is a task from my intern.

Comment: Is the `student_id` column allowed to have null as a value? The only thing I see that could be changed is the check for if the `student_id` is null. You can do `AND IFNULL(table_A.student_id, '') = ''`

Comment: yup, the student_id allowed to have null or even empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like an `UPDATE` statement, rather than an `INSERT`.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.student_id = B.student_id
FROM table_A A
INNER JOIN table_B B
  ON A.last_name = B.last_name 
  AND A.email = B.email
WHERE (A.student_id ='' OR A.student_id IS NULL)
```

Notice you compare student_id to `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`.  Parentheses are important as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, after some modification, It works

Answer (score 0):

Anyway try this:

```
INSERT INTO table_A (STUDENT_ID)
SELECT B.student_id 
    From table_B AS B, TABLE_A AS A
    WHERE (A.last_name = B.last_name AND A.email = B.email )
        OR A.STUDENT_ID ='' OR A.STUDENT_ID IS NULL
```